# Add repeating table when user submits?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

I am using InfoPath and SharePoint, I have a question about a comment section and a repeating table. What I want to be able to happen is that once the comments are submitted a repeating table is added and the value of the comment is added as a read-only, in order to have a history of the previous comments. Right now I have the default value of the repeating table set to the comments, and I am not updating the value when the formula is recalculated. This should do what I want it to, but I have to manually click "insert item" in the repeating table in order to see the comment. Is it possible to add a repeating table once the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: basically...I want to know if instead of clicking the specified "insert item" you can just click a user added button to add an item in a repeating table